# What is check h2 database after unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit, h2

I have use h2 database for unit test follow [this example](https://github.com/in28minutes/spring-boot-examples/tree/master/spring-boot-2-myBatis-with-h2).

In my application.properties:

```
server.port=8888
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

In unit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class CustomerServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerDao customerDao;

    @Test
    public void testCreateCustomer(){
        BigDecimal id = customerDao.createCustomer(new Customer(1, "PhucN"));
        Assert.assertEquals(id,1);
    }
}
```

I have a problem, when I run unit test, h2 database create in memory but after finish test, database is drop and I cannot check data insert into h2 database.

Update question: I use mybatis, it's not ORM(hibernate, JPA)

Comment: Do you need the database schema to persist after the tests are finished?

Comment: @StaticBeagle yep, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this example would be more complete,

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing

you supposed to test the data that you inserted during unit test with select and assertion, not check it manuly after test.

Comment: I see this example, but If I have a flow insert 4-5 table and insert many record, it is not smart.